# Nutch 1.10 won't crawl subdirectories on my site

Tags: regex, solr, nutch

I'm new to Nutch and Solr so I've probably just got something configured incorrectly, but I can't find a setting for this in any conf files.

I'm testing Nutch on a relatively small site and it will crawl any page in the root of the site, but nothing in a subdir. So when I look at the core in Solr (5.3.1) and search I can find a page `www.somesite.com/somepage.php` but none of the pages with urls like `www.somesite.com/somedir/somepage.php` are there.

I am using the following command to run the crawl script:

```
sudo -E bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/TestCrawlCore urls/ TestCrawl/ 5
```

This should take it through 5 iterations, but it only runs one and reports that there are no more URLs to fetch and exits. There are no errors in the console or hadoop log.

Result:

```
Injecting seed URLs
/opt/apache-nutch-1.10/bin/nutch inject TestCrawl//crawldb urls/
Injector: starting at 2015-10-29 09:51:55
Injector: crawlDb: TestCrawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: Total number of urls rejected by filters: 0
Injector: Total number of urls after normalization: 1
Injector: Merging injected urls into crawl db.
Injector: overwrite: false
Injector: update: false
Injector: URLs merged: 1
Injector: Total new urls injected: 0
Injector: finished at 2015-10-29 09:51:58, elapsed: 00:00:02
Thu Oct 29 09:51:58 CDT 2015 : Iteration 1 of 5
Generating a new segment
/opt/apache-nutch-1.10/bin/nutch generate -D mapred.reduce.tasks=2 -D mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1000m -D mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D mapred.compress.map.output=true TestCrawl//crawldb TestCrawl//segments -topN 50000 -numFetchers 1 -noFilter
Generator: starting at 2015-10-29 09:51:58
Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
Generator: filtering: false
Generator: normalizing: true
Generator: topN: 50000
Generator: 0 records selected for fetching, exiting ...
Generate returned 1 (no new segments created)
Escaping loop: no more URLs to fetch now
```

seed.txt

```
http://www.somesite.com
```

(I have also tried adding a trailing '/' but that didn't change anything.)

I have tried all of the following in regex-urlfilter.txt and none seem to work any differently than the others. I have a poor understanding of these filters though.

```
+^http://([a-z0-9\]*\.)*www.somesite.com/
+^http://([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\.)*www.somesite.com/
+^http://([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\.)*www.somesite.com/([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\/)*
+^http://([a-z0-9\]*\.)*www.somesite.com/([a-z0-9\]*\/)*
```

I've gone through the hadoop log extensively just to be sure they didn't get crawled in an earlier run, thinking this may be a problem with indexing in solr, but it looks like they have just never been crawled and are being ignored.

Can someone point me in the right direction here to troubleshoot this thing? I'm out of ideas and googles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your site have a robots.txt file? It may be restricted on the links it can crawl due to that. Change the Nutch logging to Debug and it might give you a better idea.

Comment: That was it exactly. There was a disallow in robots.txt. Thanks!